# Joining two layer-3 interfaces for failover

Tags: linux, load-balancing

I have a Linux machine with two USB modems each with its own SIM card and public IP address.

One of the modems may lose connectivity at some point and I want the connections to be as resilient as possible. I understand it is probably impossible to sustain existing connections, but at least once interface 1 loses connectivity, I want interface 2 to be used for new connections immediately.

What is the best way to achieve minimum downtime with two interfaces in Linux?

```
                                                ____________
                         +------------+        /            \
                         |            |       |              |
           +-------------+ Provider 1 +-------                \
           |             |            |     /                  \
    +------+--------+    +------------+    |                    |
    |     if1       |                      /                    \
    |               |                      |                    |
    + Linux machine |                      |     Internet       |
    |               |                      |                    |
    |     if2       |                      \                    /
    +------+--------+    +------------+    |                    |
           |             |            |     \                  /
           +-------------+ Provider 2 +-------                /
                         |            |       |              |
                         +------------+        \____________/
```

Comment: This is not intended as an end-device, it will operate as a router with two WANs (routers sometimes run Linux) that end-devices will connect to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest having both interfaces up all the time and tweak your routing table is such a way that:

- Your primary interface will always be preferred
- Your secondary has an IP and is ready (hot standby) but traffic is not going through (so you don't get changed too much)
- Have a second default gateway with higher metric

You can do the above using

```
ip route add default dev xyz metric 100
```

Depending on your linux distro you will be able to make it permanent by editing the post-up or if-up scripts.

Another approach, especially if you are not getting charged per-usage, is to load balance the two interfaces. I have never setup anything similar ... <strike>but it seems pretty straight forward using [lnlb](http://lnlb.sourceforge.net/gettingstarted.html)</strike>. Nope my mistake, this is for LAN/cluster load-balancing, but [this](http://tech.gaeatimes.com/index.php/archive/how-to-load-balancing-failover-with-dual-multi-wan-adsl-cable-connections-on-linux/) has an `iptables` based implementation.

UPDATE: Based on comment:

A routing table looks like the following:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.207.246.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
10.207.246.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br0
```

The default route(s) are the ones with destination `0.0.0.0`. You can see mine is:

```
0.0.0.0         10.207.246.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
```

The `metric` indicates the priority and the **lowest** number is the most preferred. For example, with two interfaces I could have the following, in which case I prefer to send traffic to my `br0` (bridge) interface:

```
0.0.0.0         10.207.246.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
0.0.0.0         10.205.243.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
```

If `br0` goes down for any reason, the second default route will be the only route and thus `eth1` will be used. Once `br0` comes back up, the preferred route will change again and point to that interface.

Now, the second approach as I understand it, uses two distinct routing tables! Using the example from the linked blog, you can see one table called `bsnl` and one table called `tata`. Each table maps to an internet provider and each one has:

1. A directly connected LAN:

   ```
   ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.1.10 table bsnl
   ```
2. A default route/gateway:

   ```
   ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table bsnl
   ```
3. And a rule which I assume maps incoming traffic to a routing table(correct me if I am wrong - reading [this](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/29/a-quick-introduction-to-linux-policy-routing/)):

   ```
   ip rule add from 192.168.1.10 table bsnl
   ```

The above configuration defined the WAN/ISP side of things (one set for each internet connection) Last, the global scope default route will decide the `nexthop` for traffic that is coming from the LAN and has to be routed to WAN. (Global scope I assume is applied for all the interfaces that do not fall into an `ip rule`):

```
ip route add default scope global nexthop via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 weight 1 \
                                  nexthop via 192.168.0.1 dev eth2 weight 4
```

The most important difference is that the last technique *uses both interfaces/connections simultaneously* performing load-balancing with the given priorities. In the above example, `eth1` is preferred 1/5th of the time (20%) which `eth2` is preferred 4/5ths (80%). Contrary, in the first setup, using two default routes, only one connection is used at any time.

Disclaimer: I have never done the second setup, so some things might be wrong or not explained in complete detail...

Hope it helps

Comment: If I have two default routes – what is the rule that is used for picking which one to use? How do I set routes to prefer some primary interface and how does that relate to "metric"? Also, I have seen some people do `ip route add default scope global nexthop via [...] weight 1 nexthop via [...] weight 1` to achieve something similar? How is that different from what you suggest?